# Homeomorphism from n-dimensional space

Tags: general-topology

Show that $R^n-B^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times[0,\infty
)$. I'm having difficulties constructing a function for this proof.

Comment: Have you tried for the case $R^1-B^1$? I think you can reuse that case in $R^2-B^2$ by rotating (and so on for futher cases), since any point in R except (0, 0) is uniquely specified by an angle $0 < \phi \le 2\pi$ and positive magnitude. But maybe this is a naive solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try $$f(v) = \left(\frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert}, \Vert v\Vert - 1\right)$$

Comment: I'm not sure how the first coordinate corresponds with $S^{n-1}$

Comment: $S^{n - 1} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is exactly the vectors of length $1$.  In the first coordinate I just normalize the vector so that it has the same direction but it's length is $1$.

Comment: haha yea thanks I realized this was a silly question as I went to bed my mind must have been elsewhere.